# How to implement horizontal gridlayoutmanager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

How to implement horizontal gridlayoutmanager with recyclerview.
Fixed row count. and horizontal scroll.
Like this...

[image: horizontal scroll diagram]

```
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

I try do this. but this is not show anything in item.

Answer (score 53):

1. [Implement RecyclerAdapter, ViewHolder.](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)
2. Instantiate `RecyclerAdapter`, set its' adapter.
3. Specify ROWSCOUNT (there are 3 rows on your picture):

   `GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), ROWSCOUNT, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);`
4. Set layout manager: `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);`
5. Show your recycler view `setContentView(recyclerView);`

[I've prepared a sample for you, check it out](https://github.com/Mogikan/Stackoverflow-samples/tree/master/HorizontalGridLayout)

Comment: What if fill rows first ? Is there a way for this ?

Comment: @Ozan Ask a new question, didn't quite get what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I just add the affirmation. This picture might proof that Recyclerview with `GridLayoutmanager` is available for horizontal.

[image: Recyclerview Grid Horizontal]