# Stack GridLayoutManager items by columns

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a GridLayoutManager which I need to be ordered first top to bottom and only then to the right

What I have now is

```
0  1  2
3  4  5
```

Ans what I want is

```
0  2  4
1  3  5
```

How do I achieve that?

Here's my code

```
layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, spanCount, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
```

Comment: What about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33887324/1306012

Comment: @BrunoBieri Thanks, but I don't want the grid to be horizontal, it makes it scroll, while I want it to be taking the whole width

Comment: Reorder your array

Comment: If you can't reorder your array, you could also write a function that maps data position into adapter position.