# Set logic fill data in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I have Recycler View to show my grid.
My data is `int[] list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};`
And I use code

```js
mRv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mRvIcon.getContext(), 5, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
mRv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

and I have result:

[image]

But I want fill data same

[image]

How I can do it?

Comment: Are you looking for horizontal scrolling? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/33863174/1782738

Comment: I think you need to modify the `LayoutManager` for this .. [Grid View version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354292/possible-to-fill-a-grid-like-view-by-column-rather-than-by-row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone. I did it.

```js
  mRvIcon.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mRvIcon.getContext(), 2, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

But I need custom `params` of item view with `width = 1/5 screen width` in `onBinViewHolder`.
Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

try to add layout manager like this

```
new GridLayoutManager(this, 5, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use horizontal mode with 4 column:

```
mRv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(mRvIcon.getContext(), 4, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
mRv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```